# Form with multiple inputs?

Tags: html, forms

I'm not a veteran, and I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to do a form with various inputs for text. I figured out how to do the mailto, redirect, e-mail subject and all that. 
My problem is: I need to have multiple separate forms of text for like: doctor name, exam name, address, etc (also, 1 select element). All going in the same e-mail.

Can anyone help me figure this out? How can I control those things?
I don't know how they are going to go in the e-mail. 
Are they going to be separated, for being in different input boxes or should I do it by hand?

A screenshot of an example of what I have to do:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PE2f.png

Comment: Post us some code and show us what you've tried. Also be careful of terminology - you need multiple fields, not multiple forms, by the sound of it.

Comment: You should check this http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: According to the question posted , you need to have multiple fields enclosed in one form . But not multiple forms ! See this link for construction of forms : http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms05.htm

Comment: I don't have a code to show, because I don't understand how it works. I want to understand how this various fields are going to work, as they are all different text inputs that will be mailed to a person. I know about this basic form skills, my doubt is about those multiple fields, how they work toghether. How will be the output of all this fields.